# Calling C code from an R package, within C

Tags: c, r

Is it possible to call C (or C++) functions from an existing R package, within additional C code?

For example, the function `marginTable()` in my package `rje` uses a C function of the same name.  I want to create a new package which contains more C code, some of which could make use of the C version of `marginTable()`.  Can I call that function from within the new C code, other than just by copying the C code to the new file and package?

Or is it just bad practice to use internal code like this?

[Various people have asked about calling the compiled code from another R package, but all want to do it *within R*, not with C code.]

Comment: See the **[Linking To Native Routines in Other Packages Section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages)** of "Writing R Extensions"; the key seems to use a call to `R_RegisterCCallable` in `R_init_rje` in the C file (the last function in the first block of @MartinMorgan example).  Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `R_RegisterCCallable` / `R_GetCCallable` solution pointed to by @BrodieG is probably better than the one below, at least when one can modify the package where registration is required and where the choice of function to call is straight-forward (the example below came from more-or-less complicated R code that chooses one of several functions to pass to C, much like lapply's FUN argument, where choice of function is much easier to implement in R than C). Also relevant is [Linking to other packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-other-packages) when wanting to expose / access many functions.

A related possibility is to register your C functions in the rje package, using something like, in `R_init_rje.c`

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>

SEXP rje(SEXP who) {
    Rprintf("Hello %s\n", CHAR(STRING_ELT(who, 0)));
    return R_NilValue;
}

static const R_CallMethodDef callMethods[] = {
    {".rje", (DL_FUNC) &rje, 1},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_rje(DllInfo * info)
{
    R_registerRoutines(info, NULL, callMethods, NULL, NULL);
}
```

and in the NAMESPACE

```
useDynLib(rje, .registration=TRUE)
```

The address of the C-level entry point is then available in R as

```
rje_c = getNativeSymbolInfo(".rje", PACKAGE="rje")
```

and can be used in your other package by using this as an argument to a C function, e.g.,

```
.Call(.use_rje, rje_c$address, "A User")
```

with

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>

/* convenience definition of the function template */
typedef SEXP RJE_C_FUN(SEXP who);

SEXP use_rje(SEXP rje_c_fun, SEXP who) {
    /* retrieve the function pointer, using an appropriate cast */
    RJE_C_FUN *fun = (RJE_C_FUN *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(rje_c_fun);
    return fun(who);
}
```

It's too clumsy to illustrate this in a package, but the principle is illustrated by the following file `rje.c`

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>

/* convenience definition of the function template */
typedef SEXP RJE_C_FUN(SEXP who);

SEXP rje(SEXP who) {
    Rprintf("Hello '%s'\n", CHAR(STRING_ELT(who, 0)));
    return R_NilValue;
}

SEXP use_rje(SEXP rje_c_fun, SEXP who) {
    /* retrieve the function pointer, using an appropriate cast */
    RJE_C_FUN *fun = (RJE_C_FUN *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(rje_c_fun);
    return fun(who);
}

static const R_CallMethodDef callMethods[] = {
    {".rje", (DL_FUNC) &rje, 1},
    {".use_rje", (DL_FUNC) &use_rje, 2},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_rje(DllInfo * info)
{
    R_registerRoutines(info, NULL, callMethods, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Compile with `R CMD SHLIB rje.c`, and use as

```
> dyn.load("rje.so")
> .Call(".use_rje", getNativeSymbolInfo("rje")$address, "A User")
Hello 'A User'
NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, and yes there are simple examples.

See for example our (recent-ish) 
[RApiSerialize](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RApiSerialize/index.html) package 
which provides `serialize()` for use by other CRAN packages such as our 
[RcppRedis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRedis/index.html) package.

Other packages do it as well:

- [xts](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) uses C
  code from
  [zoo](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html);
- [lme4](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) uses code from 
  [Matrix](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html); and
- [expm](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/expm/index.html) which I use in [RcppKalman](http://cran.r-rproject.org/web/packages/RcppKalman/index.html).

In all examples does the *exporter* declares what is being made available, and the *importer* declares it as used.

In that setup,  R can then do the rest -- without explicit linking.